# Sort script output but keep lines together

Tags: text-processing, sort

I want to read out  some files and sort the output.

For example:

```
cat example.conf  
Order: 0   
Package: example 

cat another.conf  
Order: 2  
Package: another

cat file.conf  
Order: 1  
Package: file
```

I output them with: `awk '/Order|Package/' conf/*.conf`:

```
Order: 2  
Package: another  
Order: 0  
Package: example  
Order: 1  
Package: file
```

I would like the output to be sorted by the number after `Order:` but without breaking the relation between the lines like:

```
Order: 0  
Package: example  
Order: 1  
Package: file  
Order: 2  
Package: another
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have GNU `awk` > 4.0, and assuming the `Order` record always precedes the `Package` record, then

```
gawk '/^Order/ {order = $2} /^Package/ {p[order] = $0} 
  END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    for (i in p) {print "Order:", i; print p[i]}
  }
' conf/*.conf
Order: 0
Package: example
Order: 1
Package: file
Order: 2
Package: another
```

For older `gawk` you can use `asorti`:

```
gawk '/^Order/ {order = $2} /^Package/ {p[order] = $0} 
  END {
    n = asorti(p,b)
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {print "Order:", i; print p[b[i]]}
  }
' conf/*.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for files, which contains two lines, only.

`sed -n 'N; s/\n//p' *.conf | sort | sed -n 's/\(Package\)/\n\1/p'`

**Explanation:**

1. `sed -n 'N; s/\n//p' *.conf` - removes newline between two lines, that is, it joins two contiguous lines in to the one.
2. `sort` - sorts long lines, which was made in the previous step.
3. `sed -n 's/\(Package\)/\n\1/p'` - returns newline back to its place.

**Output:**

```
Order: 0   
Package: example 
Order: 1  
Package: file
Order: 2  
Package: another
```

Answer (score 0):

A naive Unix aproach:

```
awk '/Order|Package/' conf/*.conf |           # get your usual output
    paste - - |                               # convert two lines to one
        sort -n -k2,2 |                       # sort numerically
            awk '{print $1,$2;print $3,$4}'   # re-print in two columns
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Python script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

def get_order_package(filename):
    order=None
    package=None
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('Order:'):
                order=int(line.strip().split()[1])
            if line.startswith('Package:'):
                package=line.strip().replace("Package: ",'')
    return (order,package)

order_list=[]
for argument in sys.argv[1:]:
    order_list.append(get_order_package(argument))
order_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

for i in order_list:
    print('Order:',i[0])
    print('Package:',i[1])
```

This script defines `get_order_package()` function which parses the file, and returns tuple in format `(integer,package_string)`. We pass all files as command-line arguments and iterate over them, executing the function explained above for each one. That builds up a list, we sort it, and iterate again, printing each respective tuple parts from the new sorted list.

#### Test run

```
$ cat example_1.conf                                               
Order: 0   
Package: example_1

$ cat example_2.conf                                               
Order: 2
Package: example_2

$ cat example_3.conf                                               
Order: 1
Package: example_3

$ ./parse_conf.py  *.conf                                          
Order: 0
Package: example_1
Order: 1
Package: example_3
Order: 2
Package: example_2
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
grep -e ^Order -e ^Package `grep ^Order *.conf | awk -F: '{printf("%s:%s\n",$NF,$0);}' |sort| awk -F: '{print $2}'`
```

Explanation (below multi-line format is only for demonstration, it does *not* work in bash because the resultant single-line command cannot handle the *comments*):

```
$ grep -e ^Order -e ^Package ` \                # grep for lines starting with "Order" or "Package"; start nested command 
> grep ^Order *.conf | \                        # grep for lines starting with "Order" in files *.conf
> awk -F: '{printf("%s:%s\n",$NF,$0);}' | \     # prefixing order number with a separating colon
> sort | \                                      # sort by order number
> awk -F: '{print $2}' \                        # extract file name alone ; now filenames are ordered by the order number contained within them
> `                                             # end nested command
```